# Emulating USB device over the network

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, usb-flash-drive

**Goal**
My goal is to connect USB device over the network to another host. While doing it I want to have an access to USB packets also so that I can alter them before they reach to the other host.

**What I have tried**
I have almost searched everywhere and tested following options:

[Vhci] this module creates virtual host controller and should be able to provide API that allows one to send USB packets. But their documentation does not provide much information on how to do it.

[usbredir](https://www.spice-space.org/page/UsbRedir) This tool provides an option to have USB over IP but no documentation is given on how to send USB traffic to a client machine. I have tested it.

[USB/IP](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/) This tool connect any peripheral USB device over a network, however, it does not allow injecting packets on my own.

Please let me know how can I achieve the goal

Comment: On Windows, there's VirtualHere. Don't remember if they have Linux support

Comment: Thanks for point it out even virtual here does not allow packet level access API to alter packets before routing to the network

Comment: USB/IP is open source, it's available in the `tools/usb/usbip/` subdirectory of the linux kernel. So adapt this source to inject/alter your packets, or look at the source to figure out the network protocol, and put a forwarding/altering application in the middle. I'm not even sure how a general API to inject or alter USB packets should look like, so I'm not surprised there is none.